# How to create a table from a CSV?

Tags: snappydata

SnappyData v.0.5

I want to do something similar to loading parquet files as found in the QuickStart load scripts.

> CREATE TABLE STAGING_AIRLINEREF   USING parquet OPTIONS(path
>   '../../quickstart/data/airportcodeParquetData');

But, I have CSV files instead of parquet files.  I do not see either the "USING parquet" or a CSV version in any RowStore documentation, so I took a guess and this fails.

> CREATE TABLE STAGING_ROADS   USING csv OPTIONS(path 'roads.csv');

How can I create a table directly from a CSV file where the header row is the column names and the rest are loaded as data rows?

### EDIT

OK. Following Spark-CSV syntax, I load this file and get zero rows or table.

```
"roadId","name"
"1","Road 1"
"2","Road 2"
"3","Road 3"
"4","Road 4"
"5","Road 5"
"6","Road 6"
"7","Road 7"
"8","Road 8"
"9","Road 9"
"10","Road 10"


snappy> run '/home/ubuntu/data/example/load_roads.sql';
snappy> SET SCHEMA A;
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
snappy> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STAGING_ROADS;
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
snappy> CREATE TABLE STAGING_ROADS
(road_id string, name string)
USING com.databricks.spark.csv
OPTIONS(path '/home/ubuntu/data/example/roads.csv', header 'true');
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE STAGING_ROADS USING com.databricks.spark.csv OPTIONS(path 'roads.csv', header "true");
```

Comment: I tried this and added the EDIT above.  It runs at least, but does not create a table, nor does it load any rows in my 10 row CSV file.

Comment: OK.  I stand corrected.  Looking at the reply "0 rows inserted/updated/deleted" is wrong.  This output from the snappy-shell is deceiving because when I actually do a select * from staging_roads, I get ten rows back.  It appears I was hoodwinked by the response message!

Answer (score 1):

yes, unfortunately, the shell displays the returned set from JDBC and can be misleading for DDL commands. Notice it says the same even for 'SET SCHEMA'. 
Added a new JIRA to track this issue - https://jira.snappydata.io/browse/SNAP-940.